# Running test methods in different chrome tab

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I have 5 testNG methods. Each test methods contain a set of test cases. If am running in one chrome browser it is taking 2 hours to complete the 5 test methods. To reduce the time, I want to execute each test methods in new chrome tab. So for 5 testNG methods, it should open in 5 different chrome tabs.

Comment: Have you tried the grid implementation?

Answer (score 0):

TestNG has built-in [parallel execution](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running) implementation. You can configure it to launch tests in a desired number of threads as parallel tests, classes, etc. It will launch different instances of a browser for each parallel thread.

Comment: I am executing Test ng methods using java main method and am not using testng.xml file.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ Idea, there you can create your Run configuration and configure it as TestNG Suite, providing a path to your XML with configured parallelization. It's the easiest way I know. Or you can start using JUnit, it supports parallel execution in the code itself https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.3.0-M1/user-guide/index.html#writing-tests-parallel-execution